# snapshot.getValue(User.class) is returning null

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was working on this User information project. I have created login registration for users. The project supposed to show information about logged-in users. When users log in to their profile, it is returning a null reference.

[image: this is my Firebase database picture]

```
user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
userID = user.getUid();


    final TextView emailTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.emailAddress);
    final TextView fullNameTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fullName);
    final TextView phoneNumberTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.phoneNumber);
    final TextView carNameTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.carName);
    final TextView whereTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.where);
    final TextView availableTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.available);
    final ImageView imageViewImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    reference.child(userID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            User userProfile = snapshot.getValue(User.class);

                if (userProfile != null) {

                    String fullName = userProfile.getFullName();
                    String phoneNumber = userProfile.phoneNumber;
                    String carName = userProfile.carName;
                    String email = userProfile.email;
                    Boolean where = userProfile.where;
                    Boolean isAvailable = userProfile.isAvailable;
                    String imageView = userProfile.uriImage;

                    fullNameTextView.setText(fullName);
                    phoneNumberTextView.setText(phoneNumber);
                    carNameTextView.setText(carName);
                    emailTextView.setText(email);
                    if (where == false) {
                        whereTextView.setText("Tashkent");
                    } else {
                        whereTextView.setText("Urgench");
                    }
                    if (isAvailable == false) {
                        availableTextView.setText("No");
                    } else {
                        availableTextView.setText("Yes");
                    }
                    Uri imgUri = Uri.parse(imageView);
                    imageViewImageView.setImageURI(imgUri);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "poshol naxuy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Something wrong happened", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key of the user node that is showing in your JSON (`-MRF...J0KL`) was generated by calling `push()` in a `DatabaseReference`. It does not match a Firebase Authentication UID, so your `reference.child(userID)` ends up pointing to a non-existing node. That means that the `snapshot` is going to be empty, and `snapshot.getValue(User.class)` correctly returns `null` as no `User` exists in the snapshot.

My guess is that you add this data with something like:

```
reference.push().setValue(userInfo);
```

Instead you should be writing it with:

```
reference.child(userID).setValue(userInfo);
```

Comment: WOW great, you made my day. Thanks. For two days, I have been trying to fix this problem. The solution you provided worked for me. Thanks